# accordion when collapsed show summary of its content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

Hi all I've a set of accordion created dynamically, in case of 3 accordion I've the following generated html code:

```
<h3 value="1" id="header1" class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset 
ui-state-default ui-corner-all" 
role="tab" aria-expanded="true" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">
    <div id="text1">ACCORDION N1</div>
</h3>
<div id="content1">content of accordion n1</div>
<h3 value="2" id="header2" class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset 
ui-state-default ui-corner-all" 
role="tab" aria-expanded="true" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">
    <div id="text2">ACCORDION N2</div>
</h3>
<div id="content2">content of accordion n2</div>
<h3 value="3" id="header3" class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset 
ui-state-default ui-corner-all" 
role="tab" aria-expanded="true" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-3-e"></span>
    <div id="text3">ACCORDION N3</div>
</h3>
<div id="content3">content of accordion n3</div>​
```

Now I've created a function to display the summary of the accordion when it is in collapsed mode, here's the code:

```
$('.clickAccordion').click(function(){
            var tmpAccordionClicked = $(this);
            var tmpIndex = tmpAccordionClicked.attr('value');
            var tmpContent = $("#content"+tmpIndex);
            if(("#header"+tmpIndex).hasClass('ui-state-active')){ 
               $("#text"+tmpIndex).html("ACCORDION N."+tmpIndex);
            }
            if(("#header"+tmpIndex).hasClass('ui-state-default')){
                $("#text"+tmpIndex).html(tmpContent);
            }
    });
```

It works properly only if there's only one item in accordion, otherwise if there is more than one item, if I click on accordion n.2, accordion n.1 loses its summary. The same if I click on the third, the first is collapsed with summary and the second collapsed without summary. How can i manage that? Thanks

Comment: suggest you put this into a demo in jsfiddle.net so others can see behavior and tweak code. 3 sets of accordions or 3 levels? Again demo would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are way over thinking things. Remember, with jQuery, keep it simple.

If you instist on the manual click you can use the following:

```
$('.clickAccordion').click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("ui-state-active")) {
        $(this).find("div").html("ACCORDION N." + $(this).index());
    }
    else {
        $(this).find("div").html($(this).next().text());
    }
});
```

***HOWEVER***

There is an easier way, inside the call to the [accordion](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion) if you are using [jQueryUI](http://api.jqueryui.com):

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    activate: function(e, ui) {
        ui.oldHeader.html(ui.oldPanel.text());
        ui.newHeader.html("ACCORDION N." + ui.newHeader.index());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem that stands out to me is your if statements:

```
if("#header"+tmpIndex).hasClass('ui-state-active'){...}
```

Should probably be

```
if($("#header"+tmpIndex).hasClass('ui-state-active')){...}
```

Hope this helps. Post a working(or not) example on jsfiddle.net for better help.